# How do you guarantee a Kafka topic configuration with Spring Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a configuration bean

```
    @Bean("alertsTopic")
    public NewTopic alertsTopic() {

        return TopicBuilder.name(PORTAL_ALERTS)
            .config(TopicConfig.DELETE_RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, String.valueOf(Duration.ofHours(1).getSeconds() * 1000))
            .compact()
            .build();
    }
```

However, when I check

```
./kafka-configs.sh  --bootstrap-server kafka:9092 --describe --topic portal.alerts --all
```

It appears that none of my settings are set.

I am presuming that I may have inadvertently created the topic before I put in the configuration.  My question is how do I make my application detect that the value of `NewTopic` matches the configuration that is present otherwise terminate the application context.

Or force it to update.

Answer (score 0):

The only modifications the `KafkaAdmin` will make, if a topic already exists, is increase the number of partitions.

For other changes you must use an `AdminClient` yourself.